# UIAlertView's delegate deallocating before it is dismissed

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, automatic-ref-counting, uialertview

In my app I have a seperate object to deal with authenticating and getting information my app needs from a websevice to populate a table, lets call it Getter.

So first my View Controller I allocate getter

```
Getter *get = [[Getter alloc]init];
[get getInfoWithCompletion^(id result) {
    if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSMutableArray class]]) {
        NSMutableArray *array = result;
        self.infoarray = array;
        self.tableView.scrollEnabled = TRUE;
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
}];
```

When Getter is told to getinfo, it allocates a Downloader object, tells it to download with a url and gives it a completion block. When downloader is done it calls a completion block.

Getter.m

```
- (void)getInfoWithCompletion:(void (^)(id result))completionBlock{
     self.completion = completionBlock;
     Downloader *download = [[Downloader alloc]init];
     [downloader downloadWithURL:@"http://....." completion:^(id results, NSError *error){
            if (error) {
                [self handleErrorWithError:error];
            } else {
                ....
                self.completion(theResult);
            }
     }];

- (void)handleErrorWithError:(NSError *)error {
     UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:error.localizedDescription delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Skip" otherButtonTitles:@"Retry",nil];
    [alert show];
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
if ([[alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex]isEqualToString:@"Retry"]) {
    [self getInfoWithCompletion:self.completion];
} else {
    self.completion(nil);
}
```

The issue here is that after the alert view is shown, Getter is deallocated, so when the alert tries tell the delegate which button was tapped, it crashes. Prior to ARC, you could just go [self retain] before the alert and [self release] in the delegate method. But I can't do that with ARC. Alternatively I can just call self.completion(error) and let the view controller deal with it, but it is more reusable to have the Getter handle it so I don't have to copy error handling code every time I use it. Since I can't manually retain with ARC, how can I make sure that Getter stays alive after the alert view is shown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make Getter a property of the class, and implicitly an instance variable.

Answer (score 0):

In ARC the equivalent of a `retain` is storing the instance into a `strong` property. This could be explicitly or by adding it to an array (like the `childViewControllers` of the `UIViewController` class). Doing this will keep the instance alive until you nil the property or remove the instance from the array.

Answer (score 0):

Dont' forget, blocks are allocated on the stack, so they vanish with the context that created them. If you copy a block, the copy is placed in the heap, so it can live after the block creating code has returned. I'm not sure what the lifetime of the block allocated in the View Controller is, but you can keep it around this way if you need:

`self.completion = [completionBlock copy];`